# HK2: Bind to implementation of interface using Immediate scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, glassfish, hk2

I am building an application which will run on Jetty Server. My main class is extended from ResourceConfig to start the "javax.ws.rs.Application" init parameter is set to this class. I have also used ServiceLocator to return the service instances on demand; also used AbstractBinder to bind the class with the Singleton & Immediate scope.

My ResourceConfig class code related to dependency injection looks like this:

```
public class MyServer extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public MyServer() {
      packages("My.REST");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Server server = new Server(MythreadPool);

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfig.addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));

    //Code for connector porperties
    server.addConnector(connector);
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    server.setHandler(contexts);

    final WebAppContext webApp = setupWebAppContext(contexts, conf);


    ServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create("my-locator");
    ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(serviceLocator);
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(
        sharedServiceLocator,
        new AbstractBinder() {
          @Override
          protected void configure() {
            bind(ClassA.class).to(InterfaceService.class).in(Immediate.class);
          }
         });
    }

    webApp.addEventListener(
        new ServletContextListener() {
          @Override
          public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            servletContextEvent
                .getServletContext()
                .setAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR, serviceLocator);
          }

          @Override
          public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {}
        });

    setupRestApiContextHandler(webApp, conf);

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while running jettyServer", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

private static WebAppContext setupWebAppContext(ContextHandlerCollection contexts, Configuration conf) {
    WebAppContext webApp = new WebAppContext();
    webApp.setContextPath(conf.getServerContextPath());
    webApp.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet()), "/*");
    contexts.addHandler(webApp);

    webApp.addFilter(new FilterHolder(MyFilter.class), "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    webApp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed","true");

    return webApp;
}

private static void setupRestApiContextHandler(WebAppContext webapp, Configuration conf) {
    final ServletHolder servletHolder =
        new ServletHolder(new org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer());

    servletHolder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", MyServer.class.getName());
    servletHolder.setName("rest");
    servletHolder.setForcedPath("rest");
    webapp.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
    webapp.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/*");

    webapp.setInitParameter("shiroConfigLocations", "ShiroFilePathURI");
      webapp
          .addFilter(ShiroFilter.class, "/MyRestApiPath/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class))
          .setInitParameter("staticSecurityManagerEnabled", "true");
      webapp.addEventListener(new EnvironmentLoaderListener());
    }
  }
```

My ClassA looks like this:

```
public class ClassA implements InterfaceService {
    @Inject
    public ClassA(SomeClass instances){
     //initialize some variable
    }
}
```

There is a REST class in which the InterfaceService is injected:

```
@Path("/my_rest")
@Produces("application/json")
@Singleton
public class RestApi {

  private InterfaceService interfaceService;

  @Inject
  public RestApi(InterfaceService interfaceService) {
    this.interfaceService = interfaceService;
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get this exception:

> "javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
>   1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an active context for org.glassfish.hk2.api.Immediate
>   2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: While attempting to create a service for SystemDescriptor(
>       implementation=ClassA
>       contracts={InterfaceService}"

- In MyServer class when I bind the class with the Singleton scope it works as expected. i.e. 
  `bind(ClassA.class).to(InterfaceService.class).in(Singleton.class);`
- Then if I update my RestApi class to below

```
@Path("/my_rest")
@Produces("application/json")
@Singleton
public class RestApi {

  private ClassA classA;

  @Inject
  public RestApi(ClassA classA) {
    this.classA = classA;
  }
}
```

Then everything works as expected, with the immediate scope as well.

For me changing the scope to Immediate is required since I need to do certain operations in the class on server startup. Also, I cannot use the reference of `ClassA` in the RestApi since, there will be other implementations of the `InterfaceService` interface in the future, so I need to code to the interface in `RestApi`.
Any clue on what I need to do to get the code working with immediate scope, with binding it to the `InterfaceService`

Comment: Can you show the whole set up code where you set up Jersey and Jetty (or even a small _minimal_ repo would be great).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha: I have added the jetty server code, please let me know if you need more information related to my configuration.